# How to insert a blank row when a value in a column changes? GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to using GAS, but I am trying to create a Data Entry Form to make a Production Control Sheet with Google Sheets.

One of the information required to submit this Data Entry Form is the Product ID, which is composed of 12 characters.

When this Data Entry Form is submitted, the information written in this form will be copied in a Data Base.

To copy the information, in first place a row would be added at the top of this Data Base, and afterwards, the information from the Data Entry Form would be copied in the newly added row.

**[FROM HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP PLEASE]**

When the information is copied to the Data Base, I need the Data Base to be sorted by the `MIDDLE 6 to 9 characters` of the '`Product ID`', and by the Batch Number.

And afterwards, I need a Blank Row everytime these 4 numbers of `'Product ID'` changes.

**[UP TO HERE]**

Here I share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xC8h9F41TiUjQcDZxZLKE3PiiRN5v-CrGsIKQoYQdcw/edit?usp=sharing):

In the sheet named '`DB`', I highlighted how it should look like the Data Base.

Also, I would appreciate if I get any other recommendation to optimize this sheet please!

Thanks!

I have been looking for hours already and I couldn't find an answer. I was wondering if I should create a `DUMMY` column with an `ArrayFormula` connected to the `inputed data`, to make things easier.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Retrieve source and destination sheets.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CREATE"); // Please set the source sheet name.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("EXAMPLE_DB"); // Please set the destination sheet name.

  // Retrieve values and formulas from source and destination sheets.
  let srcValues = srcSheet.getRange("C4:C7").getValues().map(([c]) => c);
  const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange("B3:K" + dstSheet.getLastRow());
  const dstFormulas = dstRange.getFormulasR1C1();
  let dstValues = dstRange.getValues().map((r, i) => {
    if (r[5] && r[5].toString()) {
      r[7] = dstFormulas[i][7];
      r[9] = dstFormulas[i][9];
    }
    return r;
  })
  const len = dstValues[0].length;
  if (srcValues.length < len) {
    srcValues = [...srcValues, ...Array(len - srcValues.length).fill(null)];
  }

  // Sort destination values.
  dstValues = [...dstValues, srcValues] // or [srcValues, ...dstValues]
    .filter(r => r.join(""))
    .sort(([a], [b]) => Number(a.split("-")[1]) < Number(b.split("-")[1]) ? -1 : 1);
  
  // Insert empty rows.
  let temp = "";
  const emptyRow = Array(dstValues[0].length).fill(null);
  dstValues = dstValues.flatMap((r, i) => {
    const t = r[0].split("-")[1];
    const tt = i > 0 && temp != t ? [emptyRow, r] : [r];
    temp = t;
    return tt;
  });

  // Put destination values to the destination sheet.
  dstRange.clearContent().offset(0, 0, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- When you want to run this script by clicking the button, please assign the function of `myFunction` to the button.
- When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I noticed that columns "I" and "K" have the formulas. This script considers these formulas.
- This script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- If you want to put the inputted source value to the top row of each group, please modify `[...dstValues, srcValues]` to `[srcValues, ...dstValues]` and test it again.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: This is very advanced coding for my little knowledge. I don't get many things: what does .map((r.i) do; why r[5] &&  r[5].toString condition is used; I don't understand dstValues = [...dstValues, srcValues]. And many things. I am sorry, but I think I should study more before understanding this code! Could you tell me where I could get more didactic information on this? I want to study it but I don't know where to search. Anyways, I will try the code and tell you if it runs as I was expecting.

Comment: @INQ_Coding Thank you for replying. About `I don't understand dstValues = [...dstValues, srcValues]`, in this case, `srcValues` is appended to `dstValues`. `...` is the spread syntax. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) About `Could you tell me where I could get more didactic information on this?`, I think that Stackoverflow is very useful for studying various situations. If these were not useful and my answer was not useful, I apologize.